# Search in outlook , dont search in specific folder X

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, search-engines

I am trying to set a search tool or any configuration for search , to search everywhere besides specific folder
( the best is that I can add and remove which folders not to search in  , but also if I can just make sure it wont search in one specific folder would be helpful )

Answer (score 0):

Both `Define a new “Search Filter” view` and `Create a Search Folder with a folder scope and filter` should be able to achieve that。 Please check the steps in this article: [Exclude specific folders in a mailbox wide search](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/867).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.